# Can't stop Prolog nodes creation by caching / memorizing

Tags: tree, prolog, memcached, proof

How can I memorize terms on a tree in Prolog?

I thought my reasoning was fine but nodes like commutation keeps adding creating more nodes with the same previous value, the program works but I would like to stop these nodes from being created.

```
name(Term,X) :- Term=..[X|_].
prop(eq,commutative).
prop(and,commutative).
prop(and,associative).
prop(Op,P):-compound(Op),name(Op,Opname),prop(Opname,P).

identity(A,A). %checks if both are the same, or returns the same in any parameter
commute(A,B):- A=..[N,X,Y], B=..[N,Y,X]. %true if B is commutation of A, or B outputs commutation of A
associate(X,Y):- X=..[N,A,B],B=..[N,BA,BB], Y=..[N,C,BB],C=..[N,A,BA].

:- dynamic proofcache/1.
proof(_,Steps) :- Steps<1, !, false.
proof(eq(A,B),Steps) :- identity(A,B),writeln(["id",A,"=",B,Steps]),!,true.
proof(eq(A,B),Steps) :-  prop(A,commutative),  (proofcache(eq(A,B));asserta(proofcache(eq(A,B))),  commute(A,R),writeln(["comm",A,"=",R,Steps]), proof(eq(R,B),Steps-1)).
proof(eq(A,B),Steps) :-  prop(A,associative),  (proofcache(eq(A,B));asserta(proofcache(eq(A,B))),  associate(A,R),writeln(["assoc",A,"=",R,Steps]), proof(eq(R,B),Steps-1)).
```

example query:

```
proof(  eq( and(t,and(t,f)), and(and(t,t),f) )  ,6).
```

Comment: This is more of a guess or where I would personally look if this were my problem comment, but better than nothing. This smells of being a [Abstract rewriting system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_rewriting_system) type problem and not a Prolog problem. I want to say it is a [confluence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluence_(abstract_rewriting)) problem, but without actually dinging into this that doesn't feel right for what you describe.

Comment: If you can get access to the book [Term rewriting and all that](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/37315354) by Baader and Nipkow it should fill in the gaps. You might also try moving this to the [CS](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) site,

Comment: Searching for [term rewriting prolog](https://www.google.com/search?q=term+rewriting+prolog&oq=term+rewriting+prolog&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.5355j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) turned up [this](http://web.cs.ucla.edu/~stott/pttr/) which has downloadable Prolog code. Not done in the same way you did it, so you would have to learn it to use it, but might help you.

Comment: If you can't get `Term rewriting and all that` then take a look at [A Taste of Rewrite Systems](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~nachumd/papers/taste-fixed.pdf)

Comment: I am tempted to put a 500 point bounty on this, but don't think anyone who frequents the tag will answer this and I would forfeit the 500 points. The answer for the points would have to implement a term rewrite system in Prolog to solve this.

Comment: The term rewrite system would have to be confluent and terminate in all cases or explain why it can not for the rules given. An answer of just patching the Prolog would not be accepted. It would also have to work with SWI-Prolog 8.x .

Comment: thanks @GuyCoder I think my problem had something to do with the cut operator I just learnt to prolog and I was assuming commas and semicolons somehow worked like shortcircuited ands and ors but apparently not, this could have been nice it existed in forms of other operators and not have to rely on the cut operator, thanks again Guy.

Comment: Please post your answer, I would like to see it.

Comment: sure, assuming there are not more errors like this I will edit as I learn more of the language.

Comment: The post what you have in your question and we can look at it for possible errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem is that I was assuming semicolons to be shortcircuited like `||` in C++ code, in consequence the terms after the `;` were being evaluated even if the previous propositions were evaluated to false, so prepending a cut operator fixed the problem.

More errors might appear as I am new to the language, here is an example of the solution, `writeln` messages helped to see the problem, `trace` could have helped too.

```
proof(eq(A,B),Steps) :- prop(A,commutative),
    (proofcache(eq(A,B),comm), writeln(["comm was cached",eq(A,B),Steps]), !;
    asserta(proofcache(eq(A,B),comm)), writeln(["comm was not cached",eq(A,B),Steps]), 
    commute(A,R), writeln(["comm",A,"=",R,Steps]),
    proof(eq(R,B),Steps-1)).
```